# adding repo to yum

Tags: linux, yum, repository

I need to install mongodb server on my linux.  To install via yum command I need to add it to my repo. Can someone guide me how to add something in my repo?

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mongodb-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

see section 1.2 on above tutorial. Also how to find my system is 32bit or 64bit and what repo to add.

Here is my uname -a
Linux vps.server.com 2.6.32 #1 SMP Thu Sep 22 13:24:07 MSD 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open shell:

type in

> sudo gedit /etc/yum.repos.d/10gen-mongodb.repo

An empty gedit window will open, there you have to paste

```
[10gen]
name=10gen Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/i686
gpgcheck=0
```

then save and you are done.