# How do I create yum repo file?

Tags: linux, yum, centos-6

I know there is a [previously asked question](https://superuser.com/questions/386254/adding-repo-to-yum), but I still have some doubts so asking again.

How do I create a yum repo file?

I know that in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` I have to create `.repo` file.  Below is the pattern:

> 1 [name ]
>
> 2 name=
>
> 3 baseurl=
>
> 4 enabled=1
>
> 5 gpgcheck=1
>
> 6 gpgkey=

Here in the `baseurl` which link should I give? I'm fully confused about this.  How do I get that `baseurl` link?  Can anyone please explain to me clearly?

I am using CentOS 6.2.

Answer (score 7):

Found this [here](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/RepoCreate.html). Hope it helps.

*The 'baseurl' line is the path that machine uses to get to the repository. If the machine has direct access to it or mounts it as a filesystem you can use a baseurl line like:*

```
 baseurl = file:///srv/my/repo/
```

*There are 3 slashes (/) following the file:, not 2. That is correct.*

If you access the file via an http or https server you would use something like:

```
 baseurl = http://servername/my/repo
```

Answer (score 1):

The baseurl is the location of the repository's files. You obtain this information from the provider of the repository.

Most repositories already provide a pre-configured .repo file which you can drop into `/etc/yum.repos.d` or a release.rpm which you can install which contains such a .repo file (this way is better since the repo can then keep itself updated).

Comment: ok now i want to install google-crome using yum. first i want create one repo file right? in that which beseurl link should i give?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i do

1. I create the Folder call RPMS
2. Then copy all the files from /Media/RHEL*/Server to /RPMS using **cp * /RPMS** when I'm in /Media/RHEL*/Server directory then it takes some minutes to copy all Rpms
3. Then i create Repo for /RPMS
4. After that i make a copy of /etc/yum.repos/rhel-source and name it
   rhel-local.repo
5. Then vi rhel-local.repo and add following lines

> [rhel-local.repo]
>
> name=rhel-local
>
> baseurl=file:///RPMS
>
> enabled=1
>
> gpgcheck=0

Finally run **yum clean all** and **yum list all**

BASEURL is the absolute path to files

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file named google-chrome.repo with the following contents:

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome - 64-bit
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```